# Determinar os índices de um vetor que devem ser subtraídos

Tags: python-2.7, lista

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60...]
```

Preciso criar uma nova lista que seja a subtração do índice posterior pelo anterior. Por exemplo:

```
b = [indice[0] - indice[1], indice[2] - indice[3], indice[4] - indice[5]...]
```

Neste caso, preciso ter como resposta os valores:

```
b = [10, 10, 10...]
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar dizendo como faço isso?

Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seja **a** um array. Utilizando *list comprehension*, fazemos:

```
a = [10, 20, 50, 80, 50, 60]
b = [a[i+1]-a[i] for i in range(0,len(a),2) if i+1 < len(a) ]
print b
```

Desta forma, estamos apenas iterando os elementos dois a dois.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/KOtk/0).

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
b = []

# i = indice anterior
i = 0
# p = proximo indice
p = 1
# Divide o tamanho total por 2
total = len(a) / 2
for x in xrange(0, len(a)):
  if x < total:
    b.append((a[p] - a[i]))
    i += 2
    p += 2

print(b)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```
a = [10, 20, 50, 80, 50, 60];
b = [];

for i in range(len(a)):
  if (i+1) < len(a):
    b.append(a[i+1]-a[i]);
    del(a[i])

print (b);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!