# Iterar índices de um vetor

Tags: array, python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40...]
```

Preciso criar uma nova lista que seja a subtração do  segundo índice pelo primeiro, do terceiro índice pelo primeiro e etc... Depois, o terceiro índice pelo segundo, quarto índice pelo terceiro e assim sucessivamente. Por exemplo:

```
b = [índice[1] - índice[0], índice[2] - índice[0], índice[3] - índice[0], índice[2] - índice[1], índice[3] - índice[1]...]
```

Ou seja, preciso iterar todas as condições, porém sempre nessa lógica o índice posterior menos o anterior.

Possuo o script abaixo, porém ele não itera todas as condições.

```
a = [10, 50, 30, 5]
b = [a[i+1]-a[i] for i in range(0, len(a)) if i+1 < len(a)]
print (b)
```

Desculpa, caso não tenha sido muito claro. Tentei ser o máximo!

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: Não está muito claro quais são os índices que serão subtraídos. Você precisa subtrair o 0 de todos os elementos i > 0, subtrair o 1 de todos os elementos i > 1, subtrair o 2 de todos os elementos i > 2, etc? E qual exatamente a diferença para esta pergunta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230085/5878)?

Comment: É isso mesmo! Que preciso.

A diferença para essa pergunta citada é que estou efetuando indice[1] - indice[0], depois índice[4]-índice[3].

Preciso que ela faça índice[1]- índice[0], depois índice[2] - índice[0] e índice[3]-índice[0]. Ou seja, é como seu eu travasse o índice[0] e efetuasse os procedimentos de subtração. Quando atingisse o fim, pulava para o índice[1], e fazia o mesmo com o índice[2] e índice[3] e assim por diante.

Consegui te explicar melhor? Desculpa qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então para obter o resultado desejado, você irá necessitar de dois laços: um para percorrer o índice que será subtraído e outro os índices que subtrairão. Isto é, a primeira parte da lista serão todos os elementos subtraindo o elemento 0, a segunda parte será todos os elementos maiores que 1 subtraindo o elemento 1, etc. O primeiro laço define o valor `x = 0, 1, 2, ..., n`; o segundo será `y = x+1, X+2, ..., n`, sendo calculado o valor de `a[y]-a[x]`. Veja:

```
a = [3, 5, 2]

resultado = []

for ix, x in enumerate(a):
    for y in a[ix+1:]:
        resultado.append(y - x)

print resultado
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/N8S0HU).

O resultado será `[2, -1, -3]`, pois é referente à `a[1]-a[0], a[2]-a[0], a[2]-a[1]`.

---

**Correção:** é necessário utilizar a função `enumerate` para iterar sobre os elementos da lista, pois ela retornará um par de valores referentes ao índice e ao valor em si. Antes estava apenas utilizando o valor, o que gerou o comportamento inesperado comentado.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @AndersonCarlos Woss. Acredito que com isso consigo prosseguir na etapa que estou do meu software.

Comment: acabei de perceber, mas quando os números da minha lista resultam em um valor negativo, por exemplo (3-4), não são exibidos na lista.
Fiz um teste com esses valores a = [3, 5, 2] e ele não exibiu nada.
Percebo que funciona corretamente, quando o resultado da minha subtração é um valor positivo. Porém quando o resultado é negativo, não funciona.
Saberia me dizer como resolvo isso?

Comment: @Danilo, pronto, acredito que o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado @Anderson Carlos Woss. Realmente está tudo OK agora!

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```
a = [10, 20, 50, 80, 50, 60];
b = [];

tamanhoLista = len(a); 

for i in range(tamanhoLista):
    subtracoes = [];
    for x in range(i, tamanhoLista):
        if (x+1) < tamanhoLista:
          subtracoes.append(a[x + 1]-a[i]);
        elif (i == (tamanhoLista - 1)):
            subtracoes.append(a[x]-a[i]);
    b.append(subtracoes);

print(b);
```

O retorno é:

```
[
    [10, 40, 70, 40, 50], 
    [30, 60, 30, 40], 
    [30, 0, 10], 
    [-30, -20], 
    [10], 
    [0]
]
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Também funciona.